# Java Mail - search and sort for reduced amount of emails together

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have currently a huge problem for which I need help for it.
Currently I´m not loading all emails at once.
I found here the following function for it:

```
Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages(start, end);
```

I know I can use SortTerm for sorting the emails:

```
SortTerm sortTerm[] = new SortTerm[] { SortTerm.REVERSE, SortTerm.DATE };
Message messages = ((IMAPFolder) emailFolder).getSortedMessages(sortTerm);
```

But than I will load again all emails.
How can I use together:
- search
- sort
- and use getMessages(start, end)

A sample code would be very helpful.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, when using IMAP no messages are "loaded" when you call getMessages.  All that happens is that the JavaMail client creates a Message object that refers to the message on the server, and sets it up so that the Message object will fetch the data for the message on the server when you ask for it.

You could create a SearchTerm that uses a pair of MessageNumberTerms to constrain the message to be within a certain range just as you were doing with "start, end".  But you should ask yourself whether you really want to sort all the messages in the mailbox first by message number (effectively a forward sort by received date) and then reverse sort them by sent date.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You are right! I thought I will load than all emails. For me scenario I create a new Object from another class "Email" for my presentation view. I have no limit the array to the "start" and "end" value which I got from my presentation view. Many thanks for your help

Comment: @BillShannon seems like ((IMAPFolder) emailFolder).getSortedMessages(sortTerm) is not working anymore? "The method getSortedMessages(SortTerm[]) is undefined for the type IMAPFolder" What should I use instead?